# react-native - Picker - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.children[position].props)

Tags: react-native

I am encountering a weird behaviour when using Picker.

I use a Picker as follows :

```
<Picker
  mode="dropdown"
  style={styles.pickerField}
  selectedValue={this.state.dayAndTime}
  onValueChange={(text) => this.setState({ dayAndTime: text })}
>
  <Picker.Item label="Le 5/07 à 15H" value="0" key="0" />
</Picker>
```

When the screen displaying this picker is loaded, I got an error screen saying (cf. screenshot below) : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.children[position].props)

From what I gathered, my problem come from line 106 of Libraries/Components/Picker/PickerAndroid.android.js, it seems that having a property "onValueChange" triggers it. I removed it, and error didn't happen.

I use react-native 0.31.0, I use an android api 23 virtual device with genymotion.

Is there something something I am doing wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
 <Picker
                  dropdownIconColor={colors.bColor}
                  selectedValue={formik.values.state}
                  onValueChange={value => changeValue('state', value)}>
                  <Picker.Item label={'Select State'} value="" />
                  {states ?                        states.map((item, index) => {
                      return (
                        <Picker.Item
                          key={index}
                          label={item.StateName}
                          value={item.StateName}
                        />
                      );
                    }):null}
                </Picker>


----------
If you return null when you don't have a array to render, It will solve the issue. But you need to provide that 
"<Picker.Item label={'Select State'} value="" />" for blank selected value.
```

Answer (score 6):

The above solutions might be the one that might solve your query. One thing I would put light on is , correct way to import:

```js
import {Picker} from '@react-native-community/picker';
```

Rather than

```js
import Picker from '@react-native-community/picker';
```

Comment: Thanks for this contribution.

I resolved my problem just by putting Picker in { }.

I had this :

```import Picker from '@react-native-picker/picker';
```
After seeing your comment , i changed my code to this :


```import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is but sometimes only the latter works as with 
`import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';`

Comment: Now it should be `import {Picker} from "@react-native-picker/picker";`

Answer (score 4):

There must be at least 2 items to pick from,  for example:

 `<Picker.Item label="Le 5/07 à 15H" value="0" key="0" />
 <Picker.Item label="Le 5/07 à 15H" value="1" key="1" />`

Also for better syntax you can try:

`onValueChange={(dayAndTime) => this.setState({ dayAndTime })}`

Comment: Thanks, I had only one item because I haven't been told about what should go in this picker. I would not have guessed that was the cause in a million years.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I wish the error was a lot more descriptive than that. Geez. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: can you help me with a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364833/react-native-picker-selected-value-gives-undefined-is-not-an-object-error)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but it was using an Item component + an array. And to fix it, I added an empty array as the default value to my dataSource prop Like that:

```
<Picker style={styles.picker} mode="dropdown" { ...props }>
    <Picker.Item label="--- Select ---" value="" />
    {
        props.dataSource.map(({ label, value }) => (
            <Picker.Item key={value} label={label} value={value} />
        ))
    }
</Picker>

PickerWithLabel.defaultProps = {
    dataSource: []
};
```