# React native picker selected value gives undefined is not an object error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-android

I am using below code for picker and to send the value selected from picker to api call, i keep getting this error Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.selected1')
what am i doing wrong?

```
'use strict'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const ReactNative = require('react-native');
const {
Picker,
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Navigator,
Text,
View,
TextInput,
Button,
ScrollView
} = ReactNative;
const Item = Picker.Item;
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import api from './utilities/api';

export default class MarkAttTab extends Component{

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {

 remarkstext: 'Remarks' ,
 buttonvalue: 'Submit' ,
 selected1: '--Select--',
 selected2: '--Select--',
 color: 'red',
 mode: Picker.MODE_DIALOG,
 };

 }


async submit() {
// Actions.HomeScreen();
const today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
const yyyy = today.getFullYear();
const hh= today.getHours();
const min=today.getMinutes();
const sec=today.getSeconds();


if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 
const fordate = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
const fordate2 = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
const username = 'testuser';
console.log(this.state.selected1);
const res = await api.getMarkAtt(this.state.selected1,this.fordate,this.fordate2,this.state.remarkstext,this.state.selected2,this.username);
// const status= res.status;
console.log('log'+res);

if(status==='success'){
  Actions.HomeScreen();
}

}


render() {

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'#008365',marginLeft:20,marginRight:20,marginTop:10}}>

        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          {"Date:"+new Date("2017-02-13").toString()}
        </Text>

        </View>

        <View style={{backgroundColor:'#1A8E74',marginLeft:20,marginRight:20,marginTop:2,paddingLeft:20,paddingRight:20}}>
        <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:15}}>Attendance</Text>
        <Picker
        style={styles.picker}
        selectedValue={this.state.selected1}
        onValueChange={(selected1) => this.setState({ selected1 })}
        >
        <Picker.Item label="--Select--" value="0" key="0" />
        <Picker.Item label="O" value="1" key="1"/>
        <Picker.Item label="P" value="2" key="2"/>
        <Picker.Item label="A" value="3" key="3"/>
      </Picker>
        <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:15}}>Reason</Text>
       <Picker
        style={styles.picker}
        selectedValue={this.state.selected2}
        onValueChange={(selected2) => this.setState({ selected2 })}>
        <Picker.Item label="--Select--" value="4" key="4" />
        <Picker.Item label="Weekly Off" value="5" key="5"/>
        <Picker.Item label="At Store" value="6" key="6"/>
        <Picker.Item label="Medical" value="7" key="7"/>
      </Picker>
        <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:15}}>Remarks</Text>
        <TextInput
        style={styles.textInputLayout}
      onChangeText={(remarkstext) => this.setState({remarkstext})}
      value={this.state.remarkstext}
    />

    <View style={styles.buttonView}>

    <Button
      onPress={this.submit}
      title={this.state.buttonvalue}
      color='#FF7323'>
    </Button>
    </View>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
    </View>
   )

   }

   changeMode = () => {
    const newMode = this.state.mode === Picker.MODE_DIALOG
    ? Picker.MODE_DROPDOWN
    : Picker.MODE_DIALOG;
this.setState({mode: newMode});
   };



  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to `bind` the `event` in `Button`, Use this part:

```
<Button
   onPress = {this.submit.bind(this)}
   title = {this.state.buttonvalue}
   color = '#FF7323'>
</Button>
```

You can define the `binding` in `constructor`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        remarkstext: 'Remarks' ,
        buttonvalue: 'Submit' ,
        selected1: '--Select--',
        selected2: '--Select--',
        color: 'red',
        mode: Picker.MODE_DIALOG,
    };
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
}
```

**Update-** `fetch` call pattern:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
    })
    .catch( error => 
        console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
    )
```

You need to `Catch the exceptions` and errors in this way.

Comment: i did this change ,i am not getting this error anymore but now i get Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Cannot"
parse@[native code]

Comment: did u define the `catch` with the `api` call, like this: `.catch(function(error) {....` ?? check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842499/react-native-possible-unhandled-promise-rejection

Comment: you mean over here ?this is in api.js file.. getMarkAtt(attendance,fordate,date2Pass,remarks,reason,username){
  var url='url';
  return fetch(url).then((res)=>res.json());
 },

Comment: yes here only, check the answers of prev comment link ques, how to catch the exceptions. check the updated answer also.'

Comment: where will the return statement go? and i got unexpected token , expected , on the catch block line

Comment: did u check the link that i attacked, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38843840/5185595 how he is using `return`, you just need to include `catch` after `.then` rest will be the same as u r using.

Comment: okay, i dont think it is going to the catch block , i could not see the log in console.. and  JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Cannot" parse@[native code] is still there..

Comment: it will go inside `catch` if any thing fails in `api` call, this issue might be coming because of the `incorrect json`, check the `json` that u are getting, it should be a proper `json`, can you attach the response in ques, will tell u whether its a proper `json` or not?

Comment: sorry ignore my last comment i was checking the wrong module,..yes it goes inside the catch block,  There has been a problem with your fetch operation: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Cannot"

Comment: it fails to parse the json, check it should be a proper json.