# "Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'child.props.value') " error with Picker component in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have come across this error when I used Picker component as follows,

```
<Picker 
   style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   selectedValue={this.props.shift}
   onValueChange={value => this.props.employeeFormAction({ 
                                             prop:'shift', value })}
>   
        <Picker.Item label='Monday' value='Monday' />
        <Picker.Item label='Tuesday' value='Tuesday' />
        <Picker.Item label='Wednesday' value='Wednesday' />
        <Picker.Item label='Thursday' value='Thursday' />
        <Picker.Item label='Friday' value='Friday' />
        <Picker.Item label='Saturday' value='Saturday' />
        <Picker.Item label='Sunday' value='Sunday' />
</Picker>
```

I have tired this solution from same community

[react-native - Picker - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.children[position].props)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035332/react-native-picker-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-child)

But it didn't work for me. Could any body suggest solution for this issue.

Comment: try setting a key to picker item.

Comment: @vijayst, No result even after adding key to picker item. Any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to not hardcode the values. This way is cleaner:

```
// inside your component (supposing is not a functional component)
_renderShifts = () => {
  const shifts = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday',
                'Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday'];

  return shifts.map((shift) => {
    <Picker.Item key={"shift_"+i} label={shift} value={shift} />
  });
}


// now your picker should render this way
_renderPicker = () => {
  <Picker 
    style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    selectedValue={this.props.shift}
    onValueChange={value => this.props.employeeFormAction({prop:'shift', value })}
  >   
    {this._renderShifts()}
  </Picker>
}
```

Comment: I am still facing the same error, eventhough I have removed hardcoded values. Could you suggest any alternative?

Comment: Could you suggest any alternative as I am still facing issue.

Comment: are you using redux to manage the changes, can you try and console.log if this.props.shift is not undefined? Btw, are you giving it flex 1 for some particular reason?

Comment: The problem was with react-native version. it's not working in 0.48, but working fine in 0.49. one more thing is  Picker is not being displayed with out 'flex: 1' or 'flexDirection: row or column'. In such a case I am unable to place the label for the picker. Could you help me here?

Comment: just for the record, if it works fine on RN 0.49 why don't just use RN 0.49? And have you considered that to use flex you need to define a height in the parent component? Maybe the problem is not the picker but the surrounding code.

Answer (score 0):

This error is also returned when the Picker is imported without the corresponding object destructuring.

**Incorrect**

```
import Picker from '@react-native-community/picker'
```

**Correct**

```
import { Picker } from '@react-native-community/picker'
```